# "'OpenApiParameter"mandatory header not working

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Azure function, where i need the mandatory Header to be passed . For that i have used   `[OpenApiParameter(RequestHeaders.Reqheader, In = ParameterLocation.Header, Required = true)]`

But when i hit the endpoint from Postman, then don't see the validation is working.

```
[OpenApiParameter(RequestHeaders.Reqheader, In = ParameterLocation.Header, Required = true)]
 public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, HttpTriggerConstants.PostParamsMethod)] HttpRequestData request)

{
//Code
}
```

What's the issue here? Any suggesations?

Comment: Can you try this: `[OpenApiParameter(name: "Request Header", In = ParameterLocation.Header, Required = true, Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]`?

Comment: Not working. Already tried the same.

Comment: Are you trying in Isolated Azure function?

Comment: Also, provide your code( excluding sensitive information)

Comment: yes it's a separate function, but same is required for couple of more functions. Its a basic Httptrigger function. No sensitive information are there :) . Its exactly as given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to implement the same in my environment in default Isolated Azure function:***

I tried to configure `OpenAPIParameter` as shown below, but this seems to act as a *normal parameter* not *Header:*

**Example code snippet:**

```cs
 [OpenApiParameter(name: "Request Header", In = ParameterLocation.Header, Required = true, Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
 [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Summary = "The name", Description = "The name", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
 [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Summary = "The response", Description = "This returns the response")]

 [Function("Function1")]
 public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route ="history/{Header}/{name}")] HttpRequestData req)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

     var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

     response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

     return response;
 }
```

[image]

I tried not passing the required/mandatory parameters, the function execution got failed:

[image]

**Postman Response:**

[image]

***After passing the valid parameters, it worked:***

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[azure-functions-openapi-extension/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints-in-proc.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/enable-open-api-endpoints-in-proc.md)

There is also `OpenApiHeader` class in which it may help to achieve your requirement. Try using `OpenApiHeader`, refer [OpenApiHeader Class (Microsoft.OpenApi.Models) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.openapi.models.openapiheader)

Comment: So for Header it's not working but for parameter its working. is it so?

Comment: yes, correct...

Comment: tried updating the Function.openApi nuget too but no result. may be its an open issue.

Comment: Created an issue ticket with Github repo. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/601